# Locus of center of an elliptical disc tangent to the coordinate planes

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d

An elliptical disc of semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$ is placed in the corner of the first octant (where $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$), such that it is tangent to the $xy, xz$ and $yz$ planes.  Find the locus of the center of the disc as its normal vector sweeps all possible orientations.

[image]

**My Attempt:**

Points on the perimeter of the disc can be parameterized as

$ r(t) = r_C + a \cos t \ u_1 + b \sin t \ u_2 $

where $u_1, u_2$ are two mutually orthogonal unit vectors that are orthogonal to $n$, the unit normal vector to the plane of the disc.  $u_1$ is along the major axis and $u_2$ is along the minor axis of the elliptical disc.  And,

$ r_C = (x_C, y_C, z_C) $

is the center of the disc.

At tangency with the $xy$ plane, we have

$ 0 = z_C + a \cos t_1 \ u_{1z} + b \sin t_1 \ u_{2z}  $

For some $t_1 \in [0, 2 \pi) $.

And by setting the $z$ coordinate of the tangent vector to $r$ (which is $r'$) to $0$, we get

$ 0 = - a \sin t_1 \ u_{1z} + b \cos t_1 \ u_{2z} $

Simple algebraic manipulation leads to

$z_C =  \sqrt{ a^2 u_{1z}^2 + b^2 u_{2z}^2 } $

Similar formulas apply for $x_C $ and $y_C$, namely,

$x_C =  \sqrt{ a^2 u_{1x}^2 + b^2 u_{2x}^2 } $

$y_C =  \sqrt{ a^2 u_{1y}^2 + b^2 u_{2y}^2 } $

Squaring $x_C, y_C , z_C $ and adding yields

$ x_C^2 + y_C^2 + z_C^2 = a^2 (u_{1x}^2 + u_{1y}^2 + u_{1z}^2) + b^2 (u_{2x}^2 + u_{2y}^2 + u_{2z}^2 ) $

But $u_1$ and $u_2$ are unit vectors, therefore, the above simplifies to

$ x_C^2 + y_C^2 + z_C^2 = a^2 + b^2 $

Thus the center of the disc lies on a sphere centered at the origin with radius equal to $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} $.

**My Question:**

I am looking for a confirmation of the above analysis.  Alternative solutions or comments are highly appreciated.  Thanks to all.

Comment: The derivation looks good. One comment is that while your concluding statement is correct that the center lies on a sphere, the question is asking for the *locus*, which is only a portion of the sphere's surface. So the question setter may want you to mathematically describe what part of the surface the locus occupies, for example by adding constraints on $r_c$.

Comment: Your proof is good and rather short. I have attempted to look for alternate proofs using for example the fact that theses ellipses are sections of cones with equations $a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2-2bcyz-2cazx-2abxy=0$ for some $a,b,c$... but to no avail... A subsequent question : I am wondering what are the loci of the foci of these ellipses...

Comment: That's a good question @JeanMarie, I'll look into that.